# select and upload multiple files to ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I'd like to be able to select a series of images, then upload the data through ajax call. Below is my html. Am unable to append the files in for loop.

```
 <form name="nameform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="file_input" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>     
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Submit" onClick="getInfo(this.form)" />
 </form>


  var oMyForm = new FormData();
  var filelenth = file_input.files;
  for (var i = 0; i < filelenth.length; i++) {
    var fileCheck = file_input.files[i];
    if (!fileCheck.type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }
    oMyForm.append('files[]', fileCheck, fileCheck.name);
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: 'URL',
    data: oMyForm,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Open the JavaScript console. Read the error message.

Comment: oMyForm.append("file", file.files[0]); using this am able to send the single file object

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pt04d754/4/

Comment: using this am able to send single file only, but i need multiple files

Answer (score 1):

```
 var data2 = new FormData();
    $.each($("#attachmentInfo :file"), function(i, file) {
        data2.append('attachmentFiles', file.files[0]);
    });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'text',
            url: 'savefile2.html',
            data: data2,
            success: function(responseData, textStatus) {

            },
            complete: function(textStatus) {

            },
            error: function(responseData)
            {

            }
        });
```